# Как разместить блок по центру в адаптивной верстке?

Tags: html, css

На первом скриншоте показано, что шаги выстроены не по центру странички. Как это исправить?
Пытался писать margin 0 auto, align-items, text-align, не получается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@media(max-width: 768px) {

    .steps {
        width: 768px;
        height: 606px;

        .container-navigation__step {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;

            .navigation__step {
                width: 200px;
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

```html
<div class="steps">
        <h2 class="steps-header">КАК ЗАБРАТЬ ПИТОМЦА ДОМОЙ?</h2>
        <div class="container-navigation__step">
            <div class="navigation__step">
                <div class="left-part">
                    <h3 class="step-number">1</h3>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Выберите питомца</h4>
                    <p class="text-step">В нашем приюте содержится более 60 собак</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation__step">
                <div class="left-part">
                    <h3 class="step-number">2</h3>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Оставьте
                        заявку</h4>
                    <p class="text-step">Через сайт или связавшись с нами любым удобным для вас способом</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation__step">
                <div class="left-part">
                    <h3 class="step-number">3</h3>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Пройдите
                        собеседование</h4>
                    <p class="text-step">Мы заботимся о наших питомцах и отдаем их только в хорошие руки</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation__step">
                <div class="left-part">
                    <h3 class="step-number">4</h3>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Познакомьтесь
                        с собакой</h4>
                    <p class="text-step">Приезжайте к нам в приют, что бы в живую увидеть вашего питомца</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation__step">
                <div class="left-part">
                    <h3 class="step-number num5">5</h3>
                    <div class="line line5"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Забирайте
                        друга домой</h4>
                    <p class="text-step">Мы поможем вам с транспортировкой</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <button class="button-step step-take">
            <p class="text-button__step">ВЗЯТЬ ПИТОМЦА</p>
        </button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то это то, что вам нужно

```
.container-navigation__step {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

блоки будут распределяться таким образом, чтобы между ними было равное расстояние по бокам

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или так

```
.container-navigation__step {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 15px;
}
```

и тогда блоки будут центрованы и между ними будет расстояние в 15px

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, подошёл больше второй вариант